# How to use Workload Identity when configuring external clusters in Argo CD?

Tags: azure-aks, argocd, workload-identity

I think Workload Identity is supported for adding external (AKS) clusters in Argo CD but I can't find a detailed guide anywhere for how to do this.

The [official docs](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/#aks) contain some info about how to configure kubelogin to achieve what I want, but this isn't a complete guide. Any ideas?